# ActiveMQ Classic JMS version compliance?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

Which version of JMS is ActiveMQ Classic 5.x compliant with? My impression is that the answer is 1.1.

Which version of JMS is ActiveMQ Classic 6.x compliant with? My impression is that the answer is 1.1 and 2.0.

Also, [this page](https://activemq.apache.org/activemq-6000000-release) says that JDK 17+ is supported by 6.x. I guess that means we cannot run 6.x on JDK 11 (or lower), right?

I can see the latest 5.x says it is Java 11+ compliant so I think it will run fine on JDK 11 or later, right? ([see here](https://activemq.apache.org/activemq-5018003-release))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest releases of both ActiveMQ Classic 5.x & 6.x fully implement JMS 1.1 and *partially* implement JMS 2. See [this page](https://activemq.apache.org/jms2) for more details on JMS 2 support.

If you need a fully compliant JMS 2 implementation I recommend you look at [ActiveMQ Artemis](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/).

Starting in 5.17.0 ActiveMQ Classic supports JDK 11 and later.

Starting in 6.0 ActiveMQ Classic supports JDK 17 and later. It cannot be run on JDK 11.

Comment: Thank you. Btw, this page (which you give here) says 5.18.x also support JMS 2.0. Is that full or partial support?

Comment: It is partial support. At this point, **no** version of ActiveMQ Classic fully supports JMS 2.